# How can one shorten mongo ids for better use in URLs?

Tags: python, mongodb

I've built a number of python driven sites that utilize mongodb as a database backend and am very happy with it's ObjectId system, however, I'd love to be able encode the ids in a shorter fashion without building a mapping collection or utilizing a url-shortener service.

Suggestions? Success stories?

Answer (score 12):

You could compress them as Base62 numbers. This doesn't save a lot of space, but it does save you a few bytes per ID. My example's Ruby, but similar usage in Python wouldn't be hard.

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > User.first._id.to_s
 => "4c76f3dd98db74697500003b"

ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > User.first._id.to_s.to_i(16).base62_encode
 => "uMarF7LmpY3bNOSn"
```

Comment: How do you decode?  Also, when looking up the resource, is it quicker to decode and then look up by _id or just add an index to the base62 encoded field?

Comment: I'm using node base62 package https://npmjs.org/package/base62  Notice the decode doesn't work properly > id
'513fce0fcaa8ed9819000002'
> enc = base62.encode(parseInt(id, 16))
'wHzaphe07ek80CC8'
> base62.decode(enc).toString(16)
'513fce0fcaa8ec0000000000

Comment: Turns out the number is too big for javascript.  I ended up using base58 encoding and splitting the number in half and it works properly.  > aenc = Base58.encode(parseInt(id.substring(0,12),16));
'GsEAfTs9'
> benc = Base58.encode(parseInt(id.substring(12,24),16));
'33jgsdqRG'
> Base58.decode(aenc).toString(16) + Base58.decode(benc).toString(16);
'513fce0fcaa8ed9819000002'
  Still curious about the index vs decoding

Comment: I used the npm package shortid - a brilliant option assuming you're workin in a node environment! (obviously won't help OP as they indicated Python) https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

Answer (score 7):

Heh, I recently wanted the exact same thing myself.

What I've ended up doing is giving every document that needs one a "public id" that is unique (like the ObjectId), but that is just an auto-incrementing number (so it'll take a while before the numbers get huge, and even longer if they're hex-encoded). This way, I can use the ObjectId internally (which I suspect is faster), and lookup externally referenced documents using their public id.

Note that there is a little performance hit when creating these public ids since each one requires an atomic update to a document (so you should only use them where you need them).

The key to creating an auto-incrementing number is MongoDB's [`findAndModify` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) to both increment a value and return the old value in a single atomic operation.

Since you're using Python, and so am I, here is the code that I'm currently using (note that it's not in production yet):

```
from pymongo import Connection
from pymongo.son import SON

db = Connection().mydatabase

PUBLIC_ID_COLLECTION = 'next_public_id'
def next_public_id():
    result = db.command(SON({ 'findandmodify': PUBLIC_ID_COLLECTION },
        query = { '_id': 'manager' },
        update = { '$inc': { 'next_public_id': 1 } },
        upsert = True       # Insert if not already existing
    ))
    manager = result['value']
    return manager.get('next_public_id', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to retain the original value then there really is not a good way. You could encode it, but the likeliness of it being smaller is minimal. You could hash it, but then it's not reversible.

If this is a REQUIREMENT, I'd probably recommend creating a lookup table or collection where a small incremental number references entries in a Mongo Collection.

Answer (score 1):

I brought this topic up a while ago on mongodb's mailing list. See if it can help you out.

[Custom _id](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4c8d1d6bd905d73a/1cdeae3b1b7d48b0?lnk=gst&q=sdotsen#1cdeae3b1b7d48b0)

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate auto-incrementing unique numbers, there's absolutely no need to use ObjectId for _id. Doing this in a distributed environment will most likely be more expensive than using ObjectId. That's your tradeoff.