# Is this a good way to shorten mongo id for url use

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to shorten mongo _id for better use in urls. I found this similar question:[How can one shorten mongo ids for better use in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261129/how-can-one-shorten-mongo-ids-for-better-use-in-urls) which I don't think the best answer is a good enough one.

I worked out my own simple way:

```
db.coll.find().limit(1).skip(:id-1);
```

Is this a good way? Will this way seriously affect the performance compared with directly find by mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using skip() to try and duplicate some form of auto incrementing ids is a bad idea, if you look at the [Advanced Queries documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D) it's noted that skip() can be very costly. The solutions outlined in the original question are generally going to be your best bet for something that's efficient.

Comment: Well... I didn't notice this line when reading doc.Thanks. I have to work out a new way now. Really hope mongo can overcome this limitation, 'cause i also use this way to do pagination.