# Compress (shorten) PHP string from 24 characters to 20

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently writing a PHP application that utilizes the Authorize.net api.  This api requires that a customer's unique id value be less than 20 characters.  I'm currently storing this unique customer id in Mongo as a MongoId object (24 characters).

Is there a way to convert a 24 character string to 20 so that it can meet the API requirements ?

Comment: What characters are used (24 digits, alphanumerical, full binary)? What characters are allowed?

Comment: `$id = substr($id, 0, 20);`  Seriously though, generate a 20 char one and map it to the 24 char one.  Probably should start with 20 and just use that.

Comment: @PetervanderWal it's a BSON datatype. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see on your referenced page, the 24-characters are hexadecimal. If customer-id may be alphanumerical you can use [base_convert](http://php.net/base_convert) to shorten the number. Unfortunately the full number is > 32bit so you need to covert it in parts to make it work:

```
// Pad with 0's to make sure you have 24 chars
$padded = str_repeat('0', 24 - strlen($mongoId)) . $mongoId;
$leastSignificant = base_convert(substr($padded, 14, 10), 16, 32); // will be 8 chars most
$middleSignificant = base_convert(substr($padded, 4, 10), 16, 32); // will be 8 chars most
$highSignificant = base_convert(substr($padded, 0, 4), 16, 32); // will be 4 chars most

// Concatenate, and make sure everything is correctly padded
$result = str_repeat('0', 4 - strlen($highSignificant)) . $highSignificant .
          str_repeat('0', 8 - strlen($middleSignificant )) . $middleSignificant .
          str_repeat('0', 8 - strlen($leastSignificant )) . $leastSignificant;
echo strlen($result); // Will echo 20

// Reverse the algoritm to retrieve the mongoId for a given customerId
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I certainly would not have thought of this.  I'm trying it out now.

Comment: If you have the GNU Multiple Precision-extension (just try) you can even go farther with a base-62-notation (17 chars): `$short = gmp_strval ( gmp_init(str_repeat('F', 24), 16), 62 );
var_dump($short);
$reverse = gmp_strval ( gmp_init($short, 62), 16 );
var_dump($reverse);`

Comment: I found this thread that suggests a similar approach, although not php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261129/how-can-one-shorten-mongo-ids-for-better-use-in-urls.  This is very helpful. Thank you for your help.